# Using ItemType for strongly typed repeater control?

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so I looked up some cool stuff about strongly typed repeater controls... the only issue is that it won't work. I have a `List<Entry>` that I've bound my repeater to. I just want to display the data. Normally I use `((Entry)(Container.DataItem))`, but from what I've read I can just declare the type in the ItemType.

Well... that's what I tried to do, but I get nothing. What am I messing up here?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="UserRptr" ItemType="HROpenEnrollment.Classes.Entry" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="UserList">
            <li class="CompoundField">
                <%# ???? I can't use Item here. %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I would guess that it's not finding my entry class... how do I get that in there? It's in the same namespace, in a separate folder.

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you were reading?  `ItemType` is a property of `RepeaterItem`, not `Repeater`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype.aspx

Comment: @dbaseman Originally I was reading http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/09/02/strongly-typed-data-controls-asp-net-vnext-series.aspx. However, after google searching, I was told that ModelType was renamed to ItemType. How am I supposed to properly use this method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it does seem to require VS 2012 / ASP.Net 4.5.  Is that what you're working with?

Comment: Well, it turns out I am not, even though I thought I was. Thanks for helping me figure it out though

Comment: maybe you could throw up the correct answer here once you get it working?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to bind data in code behind like below:

```
using (MicroGOVEntities entities = DataEntitiesFactory.GetInstance())
{
    var getGovernments = from g in entities.S_Government 
                         orderby g.DateCreated descending 
                         select g;
    rpData.DataSource = getGovernments.ToList();
}
rpData.DataBind();
```

And the ASP.NET code is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpData" runat="server"
              ItemType="MicroGOV.Entity.S_Government" 
              OnItemCommand="rpData_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%#:Item.GovernmentID %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Just an fyi for other Googlers: you can also bind the data in code front by exposing the list as a protected property and using the `DataBind` attribute on the repeater.

Comment: *`DataSource`, sorry.