# could not load type 'EDMNearClass.ProductRepository.DesTagliaP'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-applications, model-binding

I have solution with two project: one webApplication and one ClassLibrary with edmx and all entity framework logic. This work fine, but if I try to use strongly typed data, it begin the problem.

in code behind I use this function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using EDMNearClass;

namespace WebSite
{
    public partial class dettaglio_prodotto : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write(Page.RouteData.Values["DESCRIZIONE"]);
        }

        public IQueryable<ProductRepository.DesTagliaP> GetProduct_Taglie([RouteData("Id")] string itemId)
        {
            decimal ProdId = decimal.TryParse(itemId, out ProdId) ? ProdId : 0;
            ProductRepository pr = new ProductRepository();
            var myEnts = pr.taglieProdottiDesGetbyUId(1,ProdId).AsQueryable();
            return myEnts;
        }
    }
}
```

In aspx part I use this code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpTaglie" runat="server" ItemType="EDMNearClass.ProductRepository.DesTagliaP" SelectMethod="GetProduct_Taglie">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="quanitybox">
            <label for="qty"><%# Item.Codice %></label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="quantita" CssClass="input-text qty" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Intellisense working and help me to choise proprerty of `EDMNearClass.ProductRepository.DesTagliaP`, but at run time i receive error.
If I use `Eavl("Codice")` and I remove `ItemType="EDMNearClass.ProductRepository.DesTagliaP"`, all work fine.

I checked on /bin folder and EDMNearClass.dll EDMNearClass.pdb are present and updated.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - but i could imagine the repeater binding not liking IQueryable. I would bind to IEnumerable or just a List. Would something like the following work - not exact just to give you an idea.

```
 public List<ProductRepository.DesTagliaP> GetProduct_Taglie([RouteData("Id")] string itemId)
        {
            decimal ProdId = decimal.TryParse(itemId, out ProdId) ? ProdId : 0;
            ProductRepository pr = new ProductRepository();
            var myEnts = pr.taglieProdottiDesGetbyUId(1,ProdId).ToList();
            return myEnts;
        }
```

**EDIT**

I would also try to bind the repeater explicitly to the collection rather than use the select method attribute. See this answer

[Using ItemType for strongly typed repeater control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358589/using-itemtype-for-strongly-typed-repeater-control)

Comment: thanks for reply, but I tryed the same solution with Listview and is the same.
I also tryed your solution but isn't work.

Comment: With this method I solved problem, now I dont understand why, if I use, for example, `EDMNearClass.ufnGetProdottiDittaLingua_Result` (type autogenerate in edmx from TableValueFunction),in a Listview, it work.