# Show HTML for each database object

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a project for school and it looks like Facebook. When a user logs in it will get a number of posts received from the database. I am working with ASP.NET WebForms.

But how can I create something that makes HTML code for each post in the database?

This is the HTML code for a single post:

```
<article class="post">
    <header>
        <div class="title">
            <h2><a href="#">Post Title</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="meta">
            <time class="published" datetime="2015-11-01">November 1, 2015</time>
            <a href="profile.html" class="author"><span class="name">Jane Doe</span><img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <p>Post text</p>
    <footer>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><a href="#" class="button big">View Comments</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="stats">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-heart">28</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-comment">128</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</article>
```

I have really no idea how I can make this HTML blog for each database object.

The data in the database isn't that much so it isn't a problem to load all the posts at once for now.

Comment: Put a Repeater control on your page, with an proper `ItemTemplate`. Bind the Repeater control to a list of posts. check this answer and change it based on your need : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694399/2946329

Comment: yes, asp.net web forms.

Comment: well, fundamentally, you want a loop of some sort.

Comment: Do you already have the code to load the articles from the database? Do you retrieve a DataTable, or are you retrieving Model objects? It'd probably be good to show that code.

Comment: I wrote the code for visual c# first and now I have to translate it to asp.net so the code I used before isn't correct anymore. But the database returns everything as a string, then I make a string array, so each string array contains everything I need for a single post. Then I create a list for all string arrays.

Comment: What does the string array look like?  Are you having trouble parsing them into objects you can bind to a repeater?

Answer (score 0):

I would make simple database tables like these:

**Posts** table

```
PostID     - int (primary key)
Title      - nvarchar
Status     - varchar (Published, Pending, etc.)
PostDate   - datetime
UserID     - int (foreign key)
Image      - varchar (save the file name / file path + file name)
Post       - nvarchar
Likes      - int (count total)
Comments   - int (count total)
```

**Users** table

```
UserID     - int (primary key)
FirstName  - nvarchar
LastName   - varchar
Image      - varchar (save the file name / file path + file name)
```

Then inside **.aspx**, I will use a Repeater or ListView ASP.NET control and place the HTML tags inside:

```
<asp:ListView id="lvPosts" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <article class="post">
            <header>
                <div class="title">
                    <h2><a href='details.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PostID) %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></a></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="meta">
                    <time class="published" datetime='<%# Eval("PostDate", "{0: yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'><%# Eval("PostDate", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></time>
            <a href="profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("UserID") %>' class="author"><span class="name"><%# Eval("Username") %></span><img src='images/<%# Eval("UserImage") %>' alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <a href='post.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("PostID") %>' class="image featured"><img src='images/<%# Eval("PostImage") %>' alt="" /></a>
            <p><%# Eval("Post")</p>
            <footer>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="#" class="button big">View Comments</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="stats">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-heart"><%# Eval("Likes")</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-comment"><%# Eval("Comments")</a></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Inside the code-behind, I'll create a method that allows to set the data source value of the ASP.NET control.

I can also include a simple SQL statement to display each data needed by Eval() methods:

```
SELECT p.PostID, p.Title, p.PostDate, p.UserID,
u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as Username, 
p.Image as PostImage, u.Image as UserImage,
p.Post, p.Likes, p.Comments FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON u.UserID = p.PostID
// include WHERE keyword if conditions are needed
```

You might also need to use CSS to separate each post. The number of items to be displayed will be based from your query.

Hope these helps. I didn't bother checking the syntax from an IDE. Happy coding!

Comment: Good post, but I'd advocate that you use strongly typed models so you can avoid the use of "magic strings" and Eval statements. See [Using ItemType for strongly typed repeater control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358589/using-itemtype-for-strongly-typed-repeater-control)

Comment: @mason - Provided OP is working with _ASP.NET 4.5 or greater_ :)

Comment: @RahulSingh Good point. Though .NET 4 support ends next month, and I presume that includes support for ASP.NET 4.